# My Angular ngrx/store effect is not getting fired

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

1. I have an angular store
2. I have dispatched the Action, however, the effect is not getting fired.
3. What could've caused this?

Comment: Without seeing the code, the best anyone can do is guess I'm afraid

Comment: They have some good guesses below that solved my issue. the first effect was getting used (but would complete because an error wasn't handled), and I could see it in other effects by doing something like:
 tap(d => console.log({ d })),
 ofType(UserActions.ActionTypes.LoadUser),

Answer (score 1):

Effects will be disabled if they complete, just like an Observable will never fire again if it completes.

The main reason for an effect unexpectedly completing is an unhandled error. The most common cause for an unhandled error is failing to handle a non-2xx (e.g. not 200) HTTP response.

Here's an example of how it should be done:

```
mergeMap(value => {
  // essential to catchError else an HTTP error response will disable this effect
  return this.myService.makeHttpRequest(value).pipe(
    catchError(() => {
      return of({}) // in the event of an error the value {} is passed down the pipe
    })
  )
})
```

In the above code, if the HTTP request fails for some reason, the error is handled and the `@Effect` is not disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Effect always get one action and fire another to reducer. Try to add new action to you `catchError` section.

```
  @Effect()
  getToDos$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ToDoActionTypes.GetAllToDo),
    switchMap(() =>
      this.api.getTodos().pipe(
        map(todos => new GetAllToDoSuccess(todos)),
        catchError(err => of(new ErrorToDo(err)))
      )
    )
  );
```